# Postdoc interview with many inquiries

Tags: postdocs, interview

I was invited for a postdoc interview. It was 1h 30min long with 2 professors (via Skype). After the interview, they asked me to present at their lab meeting in the next 2 weeks (optional, about my PhD studies, also via Skype). In addition, they also asked me to send my PhD thesis (optional, before the meeting). So is it normal for PI to request so many things like this for non-advertised postdoc position? Should I agree to do all of the inquiries? They ask for my thesis before the meeting - it looks like a second PhD defense.

So is it a good place to work? Do you guys think this PI is too hard?

Comment: In my experience the chance of getting an offer is inversely proportional to the number of hoops they ask you to jump through. But it would still probably be good experience for you. As long as they aren't asking you to fly out at your own expense to do your presentation (something I have actually been asked to do before).

Answer (score 8):

The PI isn't asking for anything unreasonable.  In fact, I really like the idea of participating in the lab meeting via Skype.  This way the mentor can see how you interact with the whole lab without adding major inconvenience or expense.

As to "Should I agree...?"  -- if you'd like the job, you should probably do it.